# How to open Web Inspector on 10.12 Sierra?

Tags: objective-c, webview, web-inspector, macos-sierra

This works in OS X:

```
WebPreferences *prefs = [webView preferences];
[prefs setDeveloperExtrasEnabled:YES];

WebInspector *inspector = [[WebInspector alloc] initWithWebView:webView];
```

But crashes in macOS:

```
-[WebInspector initWithWebView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb1ab1ab1a
```

Is this Private API thrown out?

The code is taken [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2141954/1289683).

Comment: Hmm, not sure about the downvotes.  Someone is mad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They've renamed it: http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/189654

TLDR:

```c
WebInspector *inspector = [WebInspector alloc];

if ([inspector respondsToSelector:@selector(initWithWebView:)])
    [inspector initWithWebView:webView];
else
    [inspector initWithInspectedWebView:webView];
```

In case of future changes, just look at the [WebKit source code](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebKit/mac/WebInspector).