# Debugging WebVIew in Cocoa App on OS X 10.6

Tags: xcode, cocoa, webkit, webview

I am working on a very simple Cocoa app in Xcode 4 which targets OS X 10.6.

Basically, the app contains a WebView which loads an external URL. The app creates a simple desktop wrapper for this webpage.

The app launches and begins to load the URL, but it looks like some of the frames are not being loaded (the entire page doesnt load). The page works fine when viewed via Safari.

Debugging the app doesnt show any errors, although I am not sure if I should be listening specifically for ones from WebKit.

So, my question is, can anyone recommend approaches for debugging an issue like this? Basically, where a web page is not rendering as expected in a WebView view embedded in a cocoa app?

I found one solution, which allows you to use the web inspector in an embedded WebView:

[Is there a way to use the WebKit web inspector from a Cocoa WebView object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695038/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-webkit-web-inspector-from-a-cocoa-webview-object)

I also solved my problems which had to do with differences in the user agent string that the server was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the best approach in cases like this is to try to reduce the test case as far as possible while still reproducing the bug. For example, you can try simplifying and shortening the page you're loading to determine if there's some part of the markup that's triggering the problem. You can try simplifying your application to determine if there's some part of your application that's triggering the problem. And so on.