# Can I use the Web Audio API in a Cocoa WebView?

Tags: cocoa, webview, webkit, osx-mountain-lion, web-audio-api

I'm developing a WebKit-based mac application: a native Cocoa app that consists mostly of a WebView. The app needs to play audio and do simple DSP. I'd like to use [the Web Audio API](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/PlayingandSynthesizingSounds/PlayingandSynthesizingSounds.html) for this.

When I open a [Web Inspector on my WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/695038/765287), I'm told that `window` has a property called`webkitAudioContext`, but this property is set to `undefined`.

```
> window
[...]
webkitAudioContext: undefined
[...]
```

This suggests that the Web Audio API isn't supported in WebViews by default.  Is there a way to enable it?

Are [WebKit feature flags](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/FeatureFlags) involved somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I researched this issue on the Apple Developer forums. One poster there had the exact same question, but he didn't get a response. If no one on the Apple Forums knows how to enable Web Audio, I'm going to conclude that it can't be done, at least for the moment. What a shame.

I think the answer to my question is "no".

If this changes in the future, or if you have any evidence to the contrary, please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

For OS X 10.10 development only this thing was running for me:

Terminal:

`defaults write com.domain.myappid WebKitWebAudioEnabled -bool YES`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this with Mavericks? Also did you try this: http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/WebKitWebSettings.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here's how to enable it:

```
WebPreferences* p = [webView preferences];

if ([p respondsToSelector:@selector(setWebAudioEnabled:)]) {
    [p setWebAudioEnabled:YES];
}
```

Comment: Huh. When I try this code I get warnings and errors related to the selector 'setWebAudioEnabled:' not being defined. And, indeed, when I look in `WebPreferences.h` I don't see any flags related to WebAudio.  I'm on 10.8, but my development target is set to 10.9.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me: `[webPrefs setWebAudioEnabled:YES];`