# Can a user enable Web Inspector for my app to inspect my WebViews?

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview, webkit

I'm aware that I can [enable Web Inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695038/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-webkit-web-inspector-from-a-cocoa-webview-object) for the `WebView`s in my app by modifying user defaults for my program. But I'm concerned that an end-user could do the same thing and either learn something I'd prefer they not learn or use some surreptitious method to make my program misbehave.

So my question is: Is this behavior disabled for "release builds" (haven't actually tried to package and ship this product yet) or is there a way I can disable it if not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last I knew it wasn’t disabled—Daniel Jalkut (I think) actually took apart the Mac App Store this way, until they patched it.

You can, however, override user preferences and command-line preferences, in your main() function.

Since you want to override command-lines, you’d get the `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] volatileDomainForName:NSArgumentDomain]`, set the appropriate preference to `NO`, and then store it back.

This should override everything except if a system administrator turns on that preference for all users and forces it on—a bizarre edge case.