# Is it possible to use the Safari Web Inspector with an OSX app that contains webviews?

Tags: xcode, macos, safari, safari-web-inspector

- Note - this is not an iOS app, so I can't run it on a device or in the iOS Simulator.
- All of the examples I can find discuss hooking it up with iOS. Nothing about pure OSX development.

Comment: Are you trying to inspect a web view, or show your own embedded web inspector? The former is supported, the latter is at your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this looks like the answer:

[Is there a way to use the WebKit web inspector from a Cocoa WebView object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695038/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-webkit-web-inspector-from-a-cocoa-webview-object)

Didn't come up in my search until after posting the question!